# Ошибка с в процессе установки cakephp

Tags: cakephp

После установки и тестирования cakephp на локальной машине, вілазит такая ошибка может кто сталкивался что делать вообще ?

Error: Class 'IntlDateFormatter' not found 
File bel.my/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Type/DateTimeType.php
Line: 295

Answer (score 0):

В общем конфликт версий самого php стоит 7.0 и 7.1, изначально сделал php -v что привело к версии php7.1-intl.

Прочитав кучу всяких настроек решил прописать напрямую phpinfo() и увидеть что моделя нету.

Переустановками и посказками ... танцуя с бубном все заработало.